# Show loading screen while doing sendSynchronousRequest using NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, ios

When a button is pressed, I need to do a log in. While the sendSynchronousRequest is being called I'd like to have a "loading" indicator. I understand that it does not work to add the loading screen right before I make the URL request since the display code is not reached until after the URL request comes back with a result. I tried several things:

- Use notifcation center: Add observer and send a message, then start the loading screen. Do the actual request in the selector (which removed the loading view). This didn't seem to work.
- Create a separate thread for the URL request (gave me weird error about using web block in a non-web/non-main thread
- Create a separate thread for the loading view (didn't display anything!)

I'd like to get two responses: 1) what is the quick and dirty (but functional, working with iOS 3.2+) way to do this? 2) what is proper way to do it? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way:

```
- (void)startLogin:(id)sender {
    NSURLRequest *request = ...;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating]; // or whatever you need to get your loading screen to show
    [self performSelector:@selector(startRequest:) withObject:request afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)startRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    //Do your actual request here...
}
```

A little better: Do the request on a background thread (Forget about doing the animation on a background thread, UIKit isn't threadsafe)

Much better: Use the asynchronous methods of `NSURLConnection` from the main thread. This way, you don't block (you can block the UI with a "shield" view if you like), you can cancel the request if it takes very long (you never know on what kind of network your users are) and you don't have to worry about thread-safety.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it synchrounously you need to do it in another thread than the main thread if you want something to happen with the UI meanwhile. After the request is done you need to call the main thread to remove the loading indicator since UI operations are only allowed in the main thread.

1) Since you already have created code to create a thread etc, quickest way may to add the stuff you have after the request in a new method and call that method using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`

2) You could use an asynchrounous request instead. But I wouldn't say it's a more proper way. But you don't need to have to mess with threads in that case. In iOS4+ you could use Grand Central Dispatch,  `dispatch_async` etc, which is easier than creating threads manually.